# Subtracting double counted values from rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas and have a DataFrame that looks like the following:

```
Module  Position    Layout  Count
x       a           Desktop 50
x       a           Mobile  20
y       a           Desktop 100
y       a           Mobile  30
z       b           Desktop 80
z       b           Mobile  20
```

How would I be able to subtract the Mobile Count from the Desktop Count when the Module and Position values match to get the resulting DataFrame:

```
Module  Position    Layout  Count
x       a           Desktop 30
x       a           Mobile  20
y       a           Desktop 70
y       a           Mobile  30
z       b           Desktop 60
z       b           Mobile  20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d1 = df.set_index(['Module', 'Position', 'Layout'])
d2 = d1.unstack().diff(-1, axis=1).stack().combine_first(d1).reset_index()
print(d2)

  Module Position   Layout  Count
0      x        a  Desktop   30.0
1      x        a   Mobile   20.0
2      y        a  Desktop   70.0
3      y        a   Mobile   30.0
4      z        b  Desktop   60.0
5      z        b   Mobile   20.0
```

Comment: If I was to have a numeric index on the original DataFrame, is there a way to maintain these values instead of every column having to be numeric that is not the index?